# Публикация приложения c#.

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Создаю приложение. В основном приложение работает с БД и Репортами. На моем компьютере все работает нормально как при компиляции, так и при публикации. Но как только переношу на другой комп, и ошибка с БД и с Репортами. Как сделать так, чтобы при установке приложения, устанавливалось необходимое ПО. Или может какой урок знаете, подскажите

Comment: Конкретнее, какую СУБД вы используете, каким образом делаете "Репорты",какая ошибка возникает. А так ответ - "создать инсталлятор и включить в него необходимые компоненты".

Comment: Предположу что у вас настройки подключения к локальной БД и после установки на другом ПК ничего не работает.

Comment: net framework после публикации сам устанавливает установщик, я установил SQLEXPR_x64_RUS, строка подключения : DB = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename =| DataDirectory |\\IskoGlass.mdf; Database = IskoGlass; Integrated Security = True; User Instance = True; Trusted_Connection = Yes");

Comment: ошибка: unhandled exception has occurred in you application. if click Continue....

Comment: ошибка: unhandled exception has occurred in you application. if click Continue....
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to sql Server. the server was not found or was not axxessible..verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: sql network interfacess,error:52 -unable to locate a local database runtime instaallation.verify that sql server express is properly installed and that the local database runtime feature isenabled)

Comment: Читайте содержимое ошибок: `...the server was not found or was not axxessible..`- это как бы не прозрачно намекает..., на что?

Comment: Данная ошибка говорит от том, что вы пытаетесь подключиться к LocalDB, но он не установлен или отключен. Хотя судя по строке соединения, у вас обычный SQL Express... А что будет, если убрать  User Instance?